# Rails: Handling permissions for individual tables and composite views concisely

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling to find/understand the Rails concept for handling table permissions and permissions for composite views (and composite updates).

Logically, Create, Read, Update and Destroy permissions for tables should be at table (model) level.  If I know exactly which permissions a user has on a table, then it is possible to derive from that whether the user has the necessary permissions for any particular view (which just consists of data from one or more tables), and I should never have to repeat these permissions.

The 'Rails Way' would therefore seem to demand a controller for every table (model) that will be used by the application, in order to set permissions for that table in a precise way (using `before_action` or whatever to validate the user for the particular CRUD action).  *(Aside:  I'm not even sure if there's a good reason for not moving the permissions logic into the model itself, which is actually what I did initially before trying to adhere to convention a little more.)*

However, Rails (and possibly MVC in general?) seems to dictate that there should only be one action/view per request.  So if I want to make a view consisting of three 'index' views, one for each of the models A, B and C, I need another action/view and a new validation rule for this action.  This new validation rule, of course, shouldn't be necessary; the user is allowed to see this new composite view if they're allowed to see each of the individual 'index' views (or more precisely, the data underlying these views).

Also, any Create/Update/Destroy `params` received relating to a specific model should ideally be passed to that model's controllers for validation/execution (and there may be parameters for instances of multiple different models).  I don't think this is typically how it *is* done, however, because it would require multiple actions being called.

Have I misunderstood the Rails methodology for handling this, or is it really expected that you effectively repeat yourself with regards to Create, Read, Update and Destroy permissions for composite views (and composite updates)?

Comment: take a look at the pundit gem.

Comment: it is essential for any rails app that has different user roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off the Rails framework does not ship with any provisions for authentication (well except has_secure_password) or authorization (permissions) and is totally unopinionated on the matter.

There is no "Rails way" to handle authentication or authorization.

What Rails is geared towards is the Rails flavor of REST which is focused on exposing resources through a structured API. Each controller handles a specific resource or just a specific representation of a resource.

Note that a resource is not equal to a table. Tables are an implementation detail while resources are the abstractions that your application provides as a public API.

Of course since the framework is not opinionated towards any form of authorization you can roll your own in any fashion you want such as RBAC, ABAC etc.

Of course there are several community gems such Pundit and CanCanCan that remove the need to reinvent the wheel.

> (Aside: I'm not even sure if there's a good reason for not moving the
>   permissions logic into the model itself, which is actually what I did
>   initially before trying to adhere to convention a little more.)

There is a very simple reason why this is a bad idea. Models are not request aware and do not have the proper context for authorization.

A much better alternative is to use a component like Pundit that compliments the traditional MVC structure, but is its own separate entity - you could even call it MVCP.

Comment: Very useful to know what's out there, thanks. If it's one controller per resource, though, is it another controller every time resources are combined in some way, with another set of CRUD actions (or at least the R action and AJAX form updates) and repeated controller logic (including repeated 'authorizations' if using the Pundit gem)? If so, what is the design logic behind not allowing the action of a component view to be run before the view is generated (so that the controller logic doesn't need repeating in the composite view)?

Comment: The whole idea is that authentication logic should be handled by a separate layer. So you´re not repeating the logic of who gets to do what in your views - you just ask the policy if the user can perform the action.

Comment: Whether or not to use separate controllers for for example nested resources is a design decision and has very little to with permissions. I find it a very good practice for code organization and the SRP.

Comment: No I understand that the Pundit gem (for example) moves the actual authorization logic for a resource into its own 'Policy' class, so the 'index' logic in AsController becomes just '@all_a = policy_scope(A)'. I was asking if you would be expected to repeat this logic when combining views, and if so, why you couldn't instead generate the view for Model A by just running the index action in AsController first (i.e., point to the index *action* in AsController rather than repeat the index logic and then point to the index *view*).

Comment: Because you´re just shuffling the complexity around and making the controller responsible for the views composition, which is not its job.